# Why do I get an error when trying to execute this SQL statement on PHP Storm

Tags: php, mysql, methods

I am trying to obtain the data inputted from the form and add it to the database. I get this error

[image]
Here is my method to insert the data:

```
 protected function setUser($username, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO userslogin (username, fistname,lastname ,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);';

    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if(!$stmt->execute(array($username,$firstname, $lastname , $email , $hashedPwd))){
        $stmt = null;
        header("location:index.php?error= no execution");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Either something with `connect()` or `prepare()` because `$stmt` contains `FALSE`. Check for database function call errors.

Comment: Connect() works as I use it to view users. Thank you

Comment: Look for the error situation and then you can warn yourself with a real error message to help you fix the issues